# Erlangen program carried out explicitely?

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometry

I'm looking for a book where the Erlangen program is carried out on some example groups with explicit computations.

What I mean by "carrying out Erlangen program" is picking a specific group (say SO(n+1)) and some subgroup (say SO(n)), finding *all* invariants and their relations (and the relations between these relations and so on), and see what it means for the geometry of the natural space our group acts on (say n-sphere).
So all the work should be done in the group (including finding good parametrizations for geodesics and this kind of things) rather than in the usual space.

Anyone knows of a good reference?

Comment: This is a very expansive interpretation of the Erlangen program: ordinarily, one picks a space $X$ and a symmetry group $G$ (usually, highly transitive), and describes geometry of $X$ via multipoint invariants, i.e. functions $X^n\to\mathbb{R}$ invariant under the diagonal action (with implicit choice of the class of functions). So, if understand the question correctly, your space is $X=SO(n+1)/SO(n)$ (which is the $n$-sphere) and the symmetry group is $G=SO(n+1).$ However, one needs to specify the class of functions, and geodesics refer to Riemannian connection, which is not group-theoretic. 